# OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed - please check that ORACLE_HOME and > LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: php, nginx, oracle-call-interface

ubuntu 16.10 / nginx / php7.0 / oracle 11 xe

I'm trying to connect to the Oracle databas via PHP. And I get the following errors.

```
$conn = oci_connect('login', 'pass', 'localhost/xe');
```

> Warning: oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something
>   wrong with your system - please check that ORACLE_HOME and
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH are set and point to the right directories in
>   /var/www/blah.php on line 26
>
> Warning: oci_connect(): Error while trying to retrieve text for error
>   ORA-01804 in /var/www/blah.php on line 26

Really request variables, they will be empty. This code return empty string.

```
$test = getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')."  ".getenv('ORACLE_HOME');
print ("$test");
```

But in phpinfo() they are displayed.

[image: http://img.radiokot.ru/files/21274/medium/19bdtra7xs.PNG]

I can write environment variables to each file, but this is not an option.

```
putenv("ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe");
putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=-Wl,-rpath,/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib -L/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib -lclntsh");
```

What can I do?

Comment: Did you finally solve the problem? In that case, how? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by removing semicolon from the line ;clean_env=no in the file /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf in case of php-fpm 5.6 in CentOS 6. Hope it will help in newer PHP versions. Remember to restart php-fpm service after making changes to this file.

Answer (score 0):

We dont have the same infrastructure but I just solved this same issue in :

- Apache
- CentOS7
- PHP 5
- Oracle 12cR1

The message says :

> please check that ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are set and point to the right directories

In apache, there is a file where you can set the environment variable : 
`/etc/sysconfig/httpd`. There has to be a config file for nginx.

I added the required environment variables.
Assuming that

- ORACLE_HOME is */oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1*
- Oracle client was installed under */oracle/product/12.1.0/client*

Add :

```
ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib:/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/lib:/oracle/product/12.1.0/client/lib
```

I also added :

```
TNS_ADMIN=/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin
ORACLE_SID=<your sid>
```

After updating `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` I just restarted Apache's service httpd and that was it:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

I hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the incorrect NLS_LANG parameter. It was set to 'NA' in my case. The fix is:

Windows - The NLS_LANG must be unset in the Windows registry (re-named is best).  Look for the NLS_LANG subkey in the registry at \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE, and rename it.

Linux/UNIX - Here you simply issue the Linux command "unset NLS_LANG"